# How can I assign a value to a null node in Xpath?

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

This is the parts I need to crawl by using scrapy with Xpath:

```
<tr class="o"><td>Alabama</td><td><code>US.AL</code></td><td><code>US01</code></td><td>Ala.</td><td>-6~</td><td class="n">4,779,736</td><td class="n">133,916</td><td class="n">51,705</td><td>2</td><td>Montgomery</td><td>Alabamian</td><td>350-369</td></tr>
<tr class="e"><td>Alaska</td><td><code>US.AK</code></td><td><code>US02</code></td><td></td><td>-9~</td><td class="n">710,231</td><td class="n">1,530,700</td><td class="n">591,007</td><td>6</td><td>Juneau</td><td>Alaskan</td><td>995-999</td></tr>
```

My xpath expression is:

```
response.xpath('//tr[@class="o" or @class="e"][2]/descendant::*').extract()
```

But there is a null node in "Alaska". That is the `<td>` node after the `<code>` "US02". It does not happen in Alabama.

When I use expression:

```
response.xpath('//tr[@class="o" or @class="e"][2]/descendant::*/text()').extract()
```

to extract the text, this null node will be ignored.

But I have to comply to the format. So how can I set this null node as a space?

By the way, could anyone have a better solution to crawl this page in scrapy?

http://www.statoids.com/uus.html

Comment: <tr class="o"><td>Alabama</td><td><code>US.AL</code></td><td><code>US01</code></td><td>Ala.</td><td>-6~</td><td class="n">4,779,736</td><td class="n">133,916</td><td class="n">51,705</td><td>2</td><td>Montgomery</td><td>Alabamian</td><td>350-369</td></tr>
<tr class="e"><td>Alaska</td><td><code>US.AK</code></td><td><code>US02</code></td><td></td><td>-9~</td><td  class="n">710,231</td><td class="n">1,530,700</td><td class="n">591,007</td><td>6</td><td>Juneau</td><td>Alaskan</td><td>995-999</td></tr>

Answer (score 0):

I would be here as explicit as possible and get the data in a "by column" fashion:

```
for state in response.xpath('//tr[@class="o" or @class="e"]'):
    item = State()
    item["hasc"] = state.xpath(".//td[2]/code/text()").extract()
    ...
    yield item
```

where `State` is your `Item` class. Note that `extract()` would return you a `list`. Using an [item loader](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html) with a [`TakeFirst`](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#scrapy.contrib.loader.processor.TakeFirst) or [`Join`](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#scrapy.contrib.loader.processor.Join) processor would help you to have string values inside your item fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can select empty element which are elements that does not have a text or children

```
\*[not(text()) and not(*)]
```

So the XPATH that would select the empty element will be

```
//tr[@class='o' or @class='e'][2]/descendant::*[not(text()) and not(*)]
```

If we would like to get for example a string with value **"Empty"** we can append **concat** method

```
//tr[@class='o' or @class='e'][2]/descendant::*[not(text()) and not(*)]/concat(.,'Empty')
```

So finally you can **|** with the one that get the non empty cells

```
response.xpath('//tr[@class="o" or @class="e"][2]/descendant::*/text() | //tr[@class="o" or @class="e"][2]/descendant::*[not(text()) and not(*)]/concat(.,"Empty")).extract()
```

I hope this could help.